# Prove that $X_n \overset{p}{\to} X \iff \mathbb{E} [\min(|X_n-X|, 1)] \rightarrow 0$

Tags: probability-theory

##### Question:

$X_n \overset{p}{\to} X \iff \mathbb{E} [\min(|X_n-X|, 1)] \rightarrow 0$

##### My attempt:

Assume $X_n \overset{p}{\to} X$, then  $\mathbb{E} [min(|X_n-X|, 1)] = \mathbb{E} [|X_n-X|] \rightarrow 0$.

Now, assume $\mathbb{E} [\min(|X_n-X|, 1)] \rightarrow 0$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. By Markov inequality:
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X| > \epsilon) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X]}{\epsilon}
$$

If $\epsilon < 1$, then right hand side goes to zero and we are done. However when $\epsilon > 1$, I don't know how to proceed. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof for the first part is wrong since $\mathbb{E} [min(|X_n-X|, 1)] = \mathbb{E} [|X_n-X|]$ is not correct.

This part follows by the version of Dominated Convergence Theorem with convergence in probability in place of almost sure convergence. [You can find this result in this site as well as Wikipedia].

If $\mathbb{E} [min(|X_n-X|, 1)] \to 0$ then $ \mathbb{E} 1_{|X_n-X|>\epsilon}[min(|X_n-X|, 1)] \to 0$ which implies $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon) \to 0$ since $ 1_{|X_n-X|>\epsilon}[min(|X_n-X|, 1)] \geq \min \{\epsilon ,1 \} 1_{|X_n-X|>\epsilon}$.

Comment: And the integrable random variable that dominates $X_n$ can be for example $\max(X_n)$ ?

Comment: Dominating random variable is the constant $1$. @Nuraly

Comment: It is not immediately clear to me how we  get that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|>\epsilon) \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Just divide by $\min\{\epsilon,1\}$.